# CRM 2013 Javascript get data from another entity based on parameter

Tags: javascript, forms, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a situation that is only for users convenience, but is creating a headache for me.

Scenario:
I have (2) custom entities I am concerned with. (1) called "Job" and (1) called "Job Resource." Each have their own form. Job Resource is an N:1 Relationship to a Job.

"Jobs" is just our custom term for an awarded opportunity.

The "Job Resource" is a choice of multiple persons to be associated with that particular job. Those choices are also parameter driven to show "Is Supervisor."

The request I have is to add a "Point of Contact" on the "Job" form, and make it default the "Job Resource, (where 'Is Supervisor'=yes).

I have tried to use Quick View form, but there is no filtered choice for the supervisor or not. I believe I am left to do this with JavaScript. However, I have only done some simple web resources.

I would picture something like:

```
function xxx_pointOfContactid_onchange() {
    xxxToolkit.Common.writeToConsole("begin xxx_pointOfContact_onchange()");
    var jobResourceLookup = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("xxx_pointOfContact").getValue();
    var select = "xxx_firstname,xxx_lastname,xxx_issupervisor";

    if (jobResourceLookup != null) {
        xxxToolkit.Rest.Retrieve(
            jobResourceLookup[0].id
            , "Resource"
            , select
            , null
            , function (retrievedResource) {
                if (retrievedResource.issupervisor == 1) {
                    if (retrievedResource.firstname != null) Xrm.Page.getAttribute("xxx_firstname").setValue(retrievedResource.firstname);
                    if (retrievedResource.lastname != null) Xrm.Page.getAttribute("xxx_lastname").setValue(retrievedResource.lastname);
            } else {
                return;
            }
            , xxxToolkit.Common.errorHandler
            , true //asynchronous
        );
    }
}
```

When I tried to place this as onChange event, nothing happens.

Again, I am a JavaScript rookie, so if I apologize in advance for rookie question.

Any help appreciated. Thanks so much!

Comment: Looks like your missing the closing } for the function inside the Retrieve call. Also isn't the call your looking for xxxToolkit.REST.retrieveRecord or SDK.REST.retrieveRecord?

Comment: You can also include errorHandler to make life easier. See: https://arunpotti.wordpress.com/2014/04/07/restretrieveexample/ or https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/188667

Comment: You are using custom library. Put a debugger & see..